# Migration to Angular2: How to use injected AngularJS dependencies

Tags: angularjs, angular, migration

How Am I supposed to use an AngularJS dependency during migration to Angular2 outside the constructor? I am using upgrade module and service is not yet upgraded.

Comment: you have to first declare it in a module, show the full code, by probably you have to read first about DI in Angular2

Comment: Angular2 is fully based on components. There will not be any states as there in Angular1. Please go through the documentation first. Without having more knowledge in Angular2 you should not be supposed to ask questions like this.

Comment: @Mr_Perfect I am using the upgrade module and $state was just an example. I meant any dependency used in my angularJS project. I have read the documentation but it is not really helpful on how to use a dependency outside the constructor.

Comment: @Maximus This is just an example and I want to know how to use a not yet upgraded service from outside the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer was partially [Making AngularJS Dependencies Injectable to Angular](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#making-angularjs-dependencies-injectable-to-angular) but it was not demonstrated how to make it available outside the constructor.

Here is an example for the $log angularJS service.

Create **ajs-upgraded-providers.ts** where we declare the provider:

```
/**
 * $log upgraded provider
 */
export abstract class Log {
  [key: string]: any;
}

export function logFactory(i: any) {
  return i.get('$log');
}

export const logProvider = {
  provide: Log,
  useFactory: logFactory,
  deps: ['$injector']
};
```

Import to **app.module.ts** the declared provider:

```
import { logProvider } from './ajs-upgraded-providers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //imports
  ],
  providers: [
    //Providers & Services

    //Upgraded angularJS providers
    logProvider
  ]
})
```

**example.service.ts** How to use the angularJS service while migration takes place:

```
import { Log } from '../ajs-upgraded-providers'; //edit path accordingly

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

  constructor(private $log: Log) {}

  exampleFunction() {
     this.$log.info("Info to be logged");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ### Making AngularJS Dependencies Injectable to Angular
>
> When running a hybrid app, we may bump into situations where we need to have some AngularJS dependencies to be injected to Angular code. This may be because we have some business logic still in AngularJS services, or because we need some of AngularJS's built-in services like `$location` or `$timeout`.
>
> In these situations, it is possible to upgrade an AngularJS provider to Angular. This makes it possible to then inject it somewhere in Angular code. For example, we might have a service called `HeroesService` in AngularJS:
>
> ```
> import { Hero } from '../hero';
> export class HeroesService {
>   get() {
>     return [
>       new Hero(1, 'Windstorm'),
>       new Hero(2, 'Spiderman')
>     ];
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> We can upgrade the service using a Angular [Factory provider](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#factory-providers) that requests the service from the AngularJS `$injector`.
>
> We recommend declaring the Factory Provider in a separate `ajs-upgraded-providers.ts` file so that they are all together, making it easier to reference them, create new ones and delete them once the upgrade is over.
>
> It's also recommended to export the `heroesServiceFactory` function so that Ahead-of-Time compilation can pick it up.
>
> [— Angular Developer Guide - Upgrading (Making AngularJS Dependencies Injectable)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#making-angularjs-dependencies-injectable-to-angular)